# View not updating the screen

Tags: android, view, android-canvas

I have a View where I draw a number of lines which may change on runtime. This is my onDraw function:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    mainShape.draw(canvas);
    //canvas.drawLine(0,0, 100, 100, mStrokePaint);
    for (Rect dr : mLines) {
        canvas.drawLine(dr.left, dr.top, dr.right, dr.bottom, mStrokePaint);
    }
}
```

Yet, when I change the number of lines, it's not reflected on the screen. By debugging I checked that it indeed is changing the number of Rect elements in the mLines, and also it is in fact doing the right number of iterations in the for loop.

But somehow the screen shows the initial number of lines (3). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try calling invalidate() at the end of you onDraw. This forces the view to update itself

Comment: I realize this is an old question, however you should never call invalidate() from within onDraw().  What you effectively get is an infinite loop of redrawing the same view.